# Integral of $\int_0^b\cosh({u^a})du$

Tags: integration

Does one calculate the following integral:

$$\int_0^b\cosh({u^a})du$$
where $a \in (0,2]$ and $b>0$.

I found the results from online integral calculator as

$$=-\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{a}, \color{red}{-u^a}\right)}{a(-1)^{1/a}} + C.$$

In here, inside the gamma function, as far as I know, there is no any negatif variable. Maybe, I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is an [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), which can take negative argument

Comment: @Eugene Sirkiza, is it possible to show an example or referans, the link you shared I found for positive  one, but I didn't find for negative argument.

Comment: it does not mention that this is for a positive argument. It's integral.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the antiderivative $$I=\int\cosh({u^a})du$$ provided $a>0$, you can also express it in terms of the exponential integral function
$$I=-\frac u{2a} \left(E_{\frac{a-1}{a}}\left(-u^a\right)+E_{\frac{a-1}{a}}\left(u^a\right) \right)$$ which, in turn, can express in terms of the incomplete gamma function.